# C++ currency output

Tags: c++, floating-point, iostream, currency

I am taking a C++ course right now and have completed my final assignment. However there is one thing that is bugging me:

Though I have the correct outputs for the testing on a particular output, the `basepay` should be `133.20` and it is displaying as `133.2`. Is there a way to have this display the extra 0 rather than leaving it off?

Anyone know if it's possible and how to do it? Thank you in advance

My code is below:

```
cout<< "Base Pay .................. = " << basepay << endl;
cout<< "Hours in Overtime ......... = " << overtime_hours << endl;
cout<< "Overtime Pay Amount........ = " << overtime_extra << endl;
cout<< "Total Pay ................. = " << iIndividualSalary << endl;
cout<< endl;

cout<< "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" <<endl;
cout<< "%%%% EMPLOYEE SUMMARY DATA%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" <<endl;
cout<< "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" <<endl;
cout<< "%%%% Total Employee Salaries ..... = " << iTotal_salaries <<endl;
cout<< "%%%% Total Employee Hours ........ = " << iTotal_hours <<endl;
cout<< "%%%% Total Overtime Hours......... = " << iTotal_OvertimeHours <<endl;
cout<< "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl;
cout<< "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" << endl;
```

Comment: -1: The code should be a minimal working example. Most of the pasted code is irrelevant to the question. Could you please edit your question to reduce it?

Comment: Did the edit for you. Sorry I am still new to this and was unsure what part of the code was needed to help with my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. If unsure, you can orient on the phrase "short, self contained, correct example" as defined on http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [cout.precision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/) to set precision, and [fixed](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/) to toggle fixed-point mode:

```
cout.precision(2);
cout<< "Base Pay .................. = " << fixed << basepay << endl;
```

Comment: May be worth mentioning that `fixed` is `std::fixed` from `<iostream>` rather than something magical.

Comment: Thank you! This worked great! Gave yours the answer check because you included the std::fixed so I knew how to add it! I appreciate the help!

Comment: Is there a way to use this only once so that it doesnt set the precision for the other values?

Answer (score 12):

If you want to do it in a C++ way, **and** you can compile with C++11 flags, you can use the standard library:

```
// Note: the value in cents!
const int basepay = 10000;

// Create a stream and imbue it with the local configuration.
std::stringstream ss;
ss.imbue(std::locale(""));

// The stream contains $100.00 (assuming a en_US locale config)
ss << std::showbase << std::put_money(basepay);
```

Example [here](http://ideone.com/ayY5CM).

What advantages have this approach?

- It uses the local configuration, so the output will be coherent in any machine, even for the decimal separator, thousand separator, money symbol and decimal precission (if needed).
- All the format effort is already done by the std library, less work to do!

Comment: Yes, the [cppreference.com docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_money) insist on this. I have seen MSVC show currency formatting with just `cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision` if locale is set, but I believe this here solution is best for cross-platform.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible to do using [stream manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip). For example, set output to fixed floating-point notation, define precision (2 in your case) and define the fill character to '0':

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    double px = 133.20;
    std::cout << "Price: "
              << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << std::setfill('0')
              << px << std::endl;
}
```

In case you prefer a C-style formatting, here is an example of using `printf()` to achieve the same:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    double px = 133.20;
    std::printf("Price: %.02f\n", px);
}
```

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `cout` properties:

```
cout.setf(ios::fixed);
cout.precision(2);`
```

now `cout << 133.2;` will print `133.20`

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
int main()
{
    double a = 133.2;

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << a << endl;
}
```

Output

> 133.20

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a look at [precision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) and [fixed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed).

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double f = 133.20;

    // default
    std::cout << f << std::endl;

    // precision and fixed-point specified
    std::cout.precision(2);
    std::cout << std::fixed << f << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```